# what is int(a)(1)? is this a valid c++ syntax?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // ------- some statements ---------

    int(a)(1);

    // -------- some other statements .......
    return 0;
}
```

I saw this statement in a C++ program. This did not result in a syntax error.

What is `a` here? Is this valid C++ syntax?

Comment: Now the question is: Who in the world wrote that?

Comment: Maybe the space bar was broken.

Comment: could be the result of a macro expansion or some other form of code generation

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is okay to put the name of the variable in parenthesis:

```
int i;
int (i); // exact same
```

So in your case:

```
int a(1); // initialized with 1
int (a)(1); // exact same
```

Comment: Now for a bonus question - why !

Comment: @Martin: Types are to some extent composable, and the extra set of parenthesis allow for grouping of subexpressions. The language could have forbidden the use of parenthesis where not strictly required, but they did not. For example, `int (X)()` declares `X` to be a *function* taking no arguments and returning `int`, now, if `X` is `*Y` then it is a pointer to [...], if `Y` is `Z[10]` it will be an array of 10 pointers to functions... Parenthesis are required for grouping in many cases, so why forbid them in others? ... considering that they are allowed anywhere else where parenthesis group.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: And to add on to a more language why rather than a 'moral' why, §8/4 explicitly allows it in the grammar. And §6.8 removes ambiguity with expression-statements (`T(e)[5]` could mean declare `e` with the type `T[5]`, or cast `e` to a `T` and subscript index 5; in these ambiguous cases, a declaration is always the result).

Comment: @MartinBeckett Permissibility of `[10]a` is an artifact of the low-level nature of C arrays, not of the parser. (That is, it really is equivalent to `*(10 + a)`.)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - why it is valid is because of array arithmetic, why it is allowed is because of how the first C parser worked.

Comment: But since the operation is defined as pointer arithmetic, why, conceptually, would it not be permitted?