# Is the default value of int 1?

Tags: c++

After learning from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11751561/981787) that in C++ [It is okay to put the name of the variable in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751575/981787)
I tried this program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int (a)();
    std::cout << "if this works then deafult value of int should be " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And got output of ['if this works then deafult value of int should be 1'](http://ideone.com/MTwDu)
So, **is this true?**

EDIT::
After reading @james-mcnellis answer when i tried to assign a value to `a`, it gives an error as [assignment of function ‘int a()’](http://ideone.com/u62dh).

so now it is clear that here `a` is a function not the variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`a` is not an `int`:  it is a function that has no parameters and returns an `int`.  Because it is a function declaration, `a` is also not a local variable and it does not have a "default value."

The program is ill-formed because you never define the function `a` but you attempt to *use* it (by taking its address in the insertion expression).  It therefore violates the one definition rule.

If you define `a` in the program, `1` will be printed because the address of the function `a` will be converted to `bool`:  the `operator<<` overload that has a `bool` parameter is the best match for the function pointer argument type.

[Note:  if you define `a` and compile with Visual C++, it will print the address of the function, not `1`.  This is (I think) because Visual C++ allows a function pointer to be implicitly converted to `void*`, and then the `operator<<` overload that has a `void const*` parameter is the best match for the function pointer argument type.  If you compile with language extensions disabled (`/Za`), the overload with a `bool` parameter will be selected as expected.]

Comment: Shouldn't this cause a linker error for taking the address of an undefined function?

Comment: @ildjarn:  I would expect so.  It certainly will using the Visual C++ toolchain.  It might not be supposed to compile even if `a` is defined:  I'm not sure which `operator<<` might be used.  Visual C++ prints the address of the function (perhaps because it allows function pointers to be converted to `void*`?) and g++ prints `1` (beats me...).

Comment: g++ is using conversion-to-bool.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I tried with `g++ -Wall ...`. It complains `warning: the address of 'int a()' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]`

Comment: @ildjarn it gives linker error when a is typecasted to (void *) :: http://ideone.com/zqUWk and, after defining the a(), gcc also prints it address :: http://ideone.com/fF6NK

Answer (score 4):

As James McNellis says you're not declaring an int, you're declaring a function.

However you can get an int initialized with a default value like this:

```
int i = int();
```

And the default value is not 1, it is 0.

```
std::cout << "this prints '0': " << int() << '\n';
```

---

In C++11 you can use uniform initialization:

```
int i {};
```

The curly braces do not get confused for part of a function declaration the way parentheses do.

Comment: `int i = int();` is value-initialized; default-initialized would be `int i;`.